# How install package on different Android versions

Tags: android, parsing, package

I have a package that installs on 1 phone, running Android 7, but not on other phones that run Android 6 or 8.

I build my package and installed it on the ADB, emulators for SDK 22, 23, 26. Package installs and runs.
My build.gradle has 
`compileSDKVersion 26`, 
`targetSDKversion:26`, 
`mnSDKVersion:22`

- I build my apk and sign it. Then rename it from apk-release.apk to
  newname.apk.
- I enabled install from outside playstore on all phones. When
  uploading it to actual phones I get the following results:

WileyFox, Android 7: installs, runs

LG V30, Android 8: There was a problem while parsing your package

Samsung Android 6: exit with unknown code

I've searched up and down stackexchange and other sources, can't find an answer.

All hints greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed them before? I'm thinking you installed them and changed apk name but with the same version nr.

Comment: Anyway, I would say. Download debug version on the phone for a more verbose error message. Further more, how are you actually installing them on your devices? with adb?

Comment: I transfer the packages with google drive, install from there

Comment: I think that will cause you to install with external sd which is causing the problem I believe. Try installing with adb install.

Comment: Two problems: install from Google Drive did not work on Android 8 device, install from local storage works. Android V6 device does not except APP signed with signature version 2. Signed with signature version 1 works. Thanks for helping me on my way!